# tkMessageBox.showwarning how to choose location of pop up?

Tags: python, tkinter

I know you can use geometry to determine the location of a window or top level in tkinter, but how about for a tkMessageBox? I have a program with a tiny GUI and it appears usually in the top left of the screen, but the pop up always shoots to the middle of the screen. I just need a way to use geometry (or something like it), on the pop up.

Thank you so much to all who read!

Comment: Sorry, not possible. Tkinter just passes your request along to the OS, and the OS decides where the window goes. I tested in Linux, and the popup is always centered in the GUI; while on Windows the popup is always centered on the monitor.

Comment: If it's really important you can easily make your own popup. [Here's a template](https://gist.github.com/novel-yet-trivial/ac4816791a0a7f15497bb8f17cb32612).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was looking into this last week and found this solution, 
it works perfectly and easy to include in your code.

Centering Root Window on Screen

```
from tkinter import * 
root = Tk()


# Gets the requested values of the height and width.
windowWidth = root.winfo_reqwidth()
windowHeight = root.winfo_reqheight()

# Gets both half the screen width/height and window width/height
positionRight = int(root.winfo_screenwidth()/2 - windowWidth/2)
positionDown = int(root.winfo_screenheight()/2 - windowHeight/2)

# Positions the window in the center of the page.
root.geometry("+{}+{}".format(positionRight, positionDown))
```

I didn't write this code and can't remember where it came from, but thanks to the author anyway.